# 431: Request Header Fields Too Large error

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, bad-request

I'm creating a project that uses NestJs for the backend part and React for the frontend part. I would like to add users but there is an error that prevented it. When I make the request using Postman it works fine, but when I try it through the front, it sends a **431** error. I'm using redux/toolkit for sending requests. I'm using http://localhost:3001/. I tried to add a `"start": "nest start -- --max-http-header-size=80000"` for backend and frontend, but it didn't help me. Attached a request-response screen:

[image]

Frontend request

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { CreateUserRequest } from "../dto/create-user-request.dto";
import { User } from "../models/User";

export const usersApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "usersApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "/users",
  }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    createUser: build.mutation<User, CreateUserRequest>({
      query: (createUserRequest) => ({
        url: "/",
        method: "POST",
        body: createUserRequest,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});


export const { useCreateUserMutation } = usersApi;
```

backend main.ts

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';


async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

users.controller.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserRequest } from './dto/request/create-user-request.dto';
import { UserResponse } from './dto/response/user-response.dto';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {

  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) { }

  @Post()
  async createUser(
    @Body() createUserRequest: CreateUserRequest

  ): Promise<UserResponse> {
    return this.usersService.createUser(createUserRequest)
  }
}
```